# Converting java.lang.double to org.joda.time.Instant

Tags: java, jodatime, google-cloud-dataflow

I have looked around a lot. I am very new to Java, and I am trying to cast a Double into an Instant. The use case is for the Google Dataflow Java SDK. The Double is a UNIX timestamp from a file I read using TextIO. When I `System.out.println(row.get("timestamp"))` I indeed get UNIX timestamps. When I do `System.out.println(row.get("timestamp").getClass().getName())`, then I get `java.lang.double`. what I have is as follows:

```
static class ExtractTimestamp extends DoFn<TableRow, TableRow> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        TableRow row = c.element();
        Instant timestamp = (Instant) row.get("timestamp");
        c.outputWithTimestamp(row, timestamp);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

`java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.joda.time.Instant`

The problem is that I want to cast the UNIX timestamps that are in double to Instants so I can pass it to `outputWithTimestamp`. I believe this should be a trivial problem, but I wasn't able to find the solution yet. Thank you.

Comment: In the UNIX timestamp in milli-seconds, seconds, days?

Comment: *"java.lang.Double cannot be cast..."* please be aware of the "tiny" difference between the object type `Double` and the primitive type `double`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "cast" a `Double` to an `Instant`. You need to pass your timestamp as a [constructor argument](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html#Instant-long-):

```
Instant timestamp = new Instant(((Number)row.getTimestamp("timestamp")).longValue());
```

This assumes the "timestamp" value is in milliseconds. If it's seconds, just multiply by 1000.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that approach too, what I was missing was (`Number`) and `.longValue()`. This was very helpful thanks again.